# BuddyPress after profile content

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

In a buddypress site, on the profile page there is this line of code

```
<?php do_action( 'bp_after_profile_content' ) ?>
```

Which generates a 'flag this user link'.

What I would like to know is where this file that generates that is as I am, trying to modify it to remove that link from after the profile and place it somewhere else on the profile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

'bp_after_profile_content' is an [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), which means there are (probably) a number of other functions hooked into it that actually create the content. Search the BuddyPress source ([grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), which I can't work without, or some equivalent) for "add_action( 'bp_after_profile_content' " and you should be able to find those functions. Once you find the function inserting that link you can probably remove it with [`remove_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) and then hack things to move that link.

Comment: I've done a recursive search from the root of the server and found nothing... how is that possible :(

Comment: Could be an issue with spaces vs. no spaces. Grep with a regex to compensate or just search for 'bp_after_profile_content' by itself. You may get more spurious results but hopefully not too many.

Comment: same result, only the do_action are returned, how is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. That `do_action` really shouldn't do anything if nothing is hooked to it. I don't have a BuddyPress install or I'd look myself. Are you sure that action is the relevant code?

Comment: Positive, it's why I'm so confused, thank you anyway! I will ask on the BP forums just in case I'm missing something obvious

Comment: The function could be in a theme  or plugin file - not in BP source. Did you try commenting it out to see if the flag-user link still appears ?

Comment: The hooked function could be in the theme or another plugin but [Mr D](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1321941/mr-d) claims to have searched recursively from root. It should have been there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php do_action( 'bp_after_profile_content' ) ?>` code in your profile.php file.

- Remove link in your profile page: Simple just remove the code from your profile.php theme file.
- Put profile link to somewhere else: Put this code where you display the profile link.

Thanks